# Looks like my `ansible_ssh_pass` is ignoring in the inventory file

Tags: ansible

Here is my inventory file:

```
web1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.33.20
db1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.33.30

[webservers]
web1

[dbservers]
db1

[datacenter:children]
webservers
dbservers

[datacenter:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

When I am trying to:

```
ansible datacenter -i inventory -u vagrant -m ping -k
```

Ansible ask me to pass SSH password:

```
SSH password:
```

Why and how to say Ansible to use password from my inventory file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question `-k` is same as `--ask-pass`

Try:

`ansible datacenter -i inventory -u vagrant -m ping`